# Should Shell Infrastructure Host (sihost.exe) be accessing the internet?

Tags: windows, security, firewall

Shell Infrastructure Host (sihost.exe) is causing a Defender firewall dialog to appear requesting internet access and I am curious as to whether Shell Infrastructure Host should be accessing the internet or whether this could be malicious.

Can anyone confirm whether there is normally a firewall rule for this binary that is missing on this system, or whether sihost should not be doing this.

I have checked the hash of this binary and confirmed it is legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Firewall defaults are fine for Windows Defender.

No issue above so far as I can see. Windows Defender will block unknown (to it) apps

It was set up this way all the way through Window 7, 8 10, and now 11.

No need to make changes and (in this case above) no additional rule is necessary.

Comment: Thanks John, however, I am asking whether there is normally a rule that includes sihost.exe that is missing in this case or whether sihost is requesting access when it should not be.

Comment: So long a WD is not blocking the known app, no rule is needed.